# Create a Marker without adding it to the map?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

- How to create instance of Marker class, but without adding it to the map.

Comment: It is more than a vital for the application i am creating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [LazyMarker.java](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/source/browse/android-maps-extensions/src/pl/mg6/android/maps/extensions/lazy/LazyMarker.java) from [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/).

It doesn't physically create marker until you call `setVisible(true)` on it.

Comment: It did the work. Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by setting the `visibility` to `false`

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(
                                    new LatLng(arg0.latitude,
                                            arg0.longitude))
                            .draggable(true).visible(false));
```

---

**Edit**

```
Marker m = new Marker(new z() {

                @Override
                public IBinder asBinder() {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void showInfoWindow() throws RemoteException {

                }

                @Override
                public void setVisible(boolean paramBoolean)
                        throws RemoteException {

                }

                @Override
                public void setTitle(String paramString)
                        throws RemoteException {

                }

                @Override
                public void setSnippet(String paramString)
                        throws RemoteException {

                }

                @Override
                public void setPosition(LatLng paramLatLng)
                        throws RemoteException {

                }

                @Override
                public void setDraggable(boolean paramBoolean)
                        throws RemoteException {

                }

                @Override
                public void remove() throws RemoteException {

                }

                @Override
                public boolean isVisible() throws RemoteException {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isInfoWindowShown() throws RemoteException {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isDraggable() throws RemoteException {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void hideInfoWindow() throws RemoteException {

                }

                @Override
                public int hashCodeRemote() throws RemoteException {
                    return 0;
                }

                @Override
                public String getTitle() throws RemoteException {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public String getSnippet() throws RemoteException {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public LatLng getPosition() throws RemoteException {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public String getId() throws RemoteException {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean g(z paramz) throws RemoteException {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

And then adding it when you want like this

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position((m.getPosition())));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It is one of the options, but still the marker is added practically to the map. I wonder if there is a way to create it without adding it - like Flex Maps API.

Comment: I think that can only be done by creating a new `Marker` object using `com.google.android.gms.internal.z` like `Marker m = new Marker(new z()/* with complete anonymous inner class*/)`

Comment: @AnujMathur_07 Marker constructor should not be available to developers and it's not good to try to use it. See [this gmaps issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5281).

Comment: I didn't realize that addMarker() returned the marker object, so this little tidbit moves me on to the next thing I don't know.  Thx.

Comment: Sorry, making a marker invisible is still adding it to the map.                                var myMarkerOptions = {
    position: myLatLng,
    map: myMap
  }
 // when you want it, add it 
  var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker(myMarkerOptions)